# First Request time out then all request served

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am writing spring rest service using spring boot framework and jetty as container.
In controller I have used the callable like this.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/{key}/events", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Callable<String> getEvents(@PathVariable("key") final String key,
            @RequestParam(required = false) final String startAt,
            @RequestParam(required = false) final String maxResults) {

        return new Callable<String>() { 
         @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
             // here logic that return json string 
        }
      }
    }
```

and the servlet conatiner factory I wrote like this

```
 @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer(){
        JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory  jetty=new JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
        jetty.addServerCustomizers(new JettyServerCustomizer() {
            @Override
            public void customize(final Server server) {
                // Tweak the connection pool used by Jetty to handle incoming HTTP connections
                final QueuedThreadPool threadPool = server.getBean(QueuedThreadPool.class);
                threadPool.setMaxThreads(Integer.valueOf(200));
                threadPool.setMinThreads(Integer.valueOf(100));
                threadPool.setIdleTimeout(Integer.valueOf(100000));
                threadPool.setStopTimeout(10000);
            }
        });
        jetty.setPort(4040);
        jetty.setContextPath("/mycontextpath");
        return jetty;
    }
```

Now My problem is when I run application,

I hit the url from browser first time it not gives the output (service not available message from jetty server).

but again I hit the URL second, third, fourth time it gives me the output.

So for implementing Callable as Controller do I missing something?

I debug code and found that first time internal processing is still going on and the browser complete response...

so What I do? please suggest,

My main aim is that controller should accept more client request at particular time and respond.

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28908229/how-to-implement-an-asynchronous-rest-request-to-a-controller-using-springboot

Comment: And so does this: http://callistaenterprise.se/blogg/teknik/2014/04/22/c10k-developing-non-blocking-rest-services-with-spring-mvc/

Comment: Did you solve the issue? @Sanjay