# Where does @Async annotation go?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, api-design

I am using Spring framework to build an API for a mobile and web application. As far as I understand, the annotation `@Async` means that a new thread will be spawned to cater for this method processing. So to keep the process running asynchronously, the controller code looks like this:

```
@Async
@RequestMapping(path = "", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<ApiResponse>> DoSomething()
{
    log.info("Get something done with the request received from user ");
    return (CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> DoSomethingProcessor()));
}
```

Here I have the controller receiving requests and then sending it to a processor method (which is also `@Async`). In this case, the controller will be free to receive more requests and the requests will be running at the same time. This is the code for the processor method:

```
@Async
private ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> GetPermissionsProcessor () {
//Do things here
return new ApiResponse()
}
```

The processor calls the service methods which in turn calls the repository if needed.

**UPDATE:**
The service layer looks like this:

```
@Async
public static ApiResponse CreateRole (Object anObject) throws Exception{
    //Do things and call repository
    return new ApiResponse(x);
}
```

This is the repository code:

```
public static Integer InsertRole (Object newObject, DataSourceConfig dsc)
{
    String sql = "INSERT INTO table";
    dsc.insertObject(sql, NewObject);
    return dsc.insertObject(sql, newRole);
}
```

My question is where do I stop adding the `@Async` annotation? At the controller level or at the service level (business logic layer) or at the repository?
Or am I taking the wrong approach here? Should I only add it at the service and repository layer when there is something that requires a lot of processing?

Comment: Remove it... You already use a `CompletableFuture` which already is async. No need to add another `@ASync` . You are overcomplicating things. Also you are creating new instances of classes yourself, so adding annotations or attempting auto wiring there will not do anything as those are not managed by spring).

Comment: What if I want to remove `CompletableFuture` and just stick to Spring framework `@Async` annotation? Right now my code has a bit of both and I want to settle on one of them

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28908229/how-to-implement-an-asynchronous-rest-request-to-a-controller-using-springboot for another post confusing asynchronous method calls with async request processing.

Comment: That is a different question then the one. you ask here. There is a difference between async request processing (which relies on the Servlet API, to async method calls).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) said, I do not need to use `@Async` annotation in my classes because I'm using Java completable future and I do not need to mix it with spring framework.