# Want to send response to post request before processing it

Tags: spring-boot-maven-plugin

Unable to send response for post request before processing it

I have tried using @Enableasync annotation and Webasynctask but no luck

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/leagues")
    public WebAsyncTask<String> addLeague(@RequestBody FootballLeagues footballLeagues) {

        Callable<String> callable = () -> {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            logger.info("Inside Callable");
            return "Request Received";
        };
        logger.info("Outside Callable");
        return new WebAsyncTask<String>(10000, callable);
    }
```

I want to send a immediate response message to user once post request is made and then perform other process

Comment: Require some help.Tried multiple ways but no success

Comment: you can find answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28908229/how-to-implement-an-asynchronous-rest-request-to-a-controller-using-springboot)